# Keras custom loss function (cannot update y_pred)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I have this loss function:

```python
def bingo_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    one = tf.ones([10])
    y2 = tf.subtract(one, y_pred)
    _, indices = tf.nn.top_k(y_pred, k = 3)
    loss = tf.scatter_update(y_pred, indices, y2)
    return loss
```

The output has 10 nodes.

The loss chooses the top 3 largest outputs whose indices are stored in `indices`.

For the top 3 values, the loss is (1 - y_pred).

Otherwise, the loss is (y_pred).

This is achieved via `scatter_update`.

But I got an obscure error:

```python
File "Keras-NN-training2.py", line 104, in bingo_loss
loss = tf.scatter_update(y_pred, indices, y2)
File ".....state_ops.py", line 352, in scatter_update
ref.handle, indices, ops.convert_to_tensor(updates, ref.dtype),
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'handle'
```

My friend running on a different machine says he got

```python
TypeError: 'ScatterUpdate' Op requires that input 'ref' be a mutable tensor (e.g.: a tf.Variable)
```

I've sort of given up on this approach -- I'd rather code a new layer to achieve what I need than just the loss function which is very restrictive.  But it'd be nice to know the solution to this issue.  Thanks!